# An exemple of a strongly-continuous contraction semigroup

Tags: semigroup-of-operators

I try to prove that $P_t := e^{\lambda t (P-I)}$ (where $Pf:= \int f(y) P(\cdot , dy)\in \mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, for $f\in \mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$), is a strongly-continuous contraction semigroup (on $(\mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}^d),||\, .\, ||_{\infty})$).

But the condition $P_{t+s}=P_tP_s$ seems to me to be understood as $$P_{t+s}=P_t\circ P_s,$$ so you have to prove, for $f \in \mathcal{C}_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ that $P_{t+s}(f)=P_t(P_s(f))$ ; here I have :
$$\begin{eqnarray}
P_{t+s}f &=&e^{\lambda (t+s) (Pf-f)} \\
        &= &e^{\lambda t(Pf-f) + \lambda s(Pf-f)} \\
&= &e^{\lambda t(Pf-f)}e^{\lambda s(Pf-f)} \\
&=& P_t(f)P_s(f) \dots 
\end{eqnarray}$$
which is a product and not a composition... 
Where is the catch?

Comment: You misunderstood the definition of $P_t$; $$P_t f = e^{\lambda t(P-I)}f = \sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(\lambda t (P-I))^n}{n!} f.$$ In particular, $$P_t f \neq e^{\lambda t(P-I)f}.$$

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome.